# Usage info through Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

Just did not find the method to retrieve the info on the usage of Google Drive such as how much space in total, how much left or how much filled up. It would be great if we do not have to do the math ourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about the account from the [drive.about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) method. It may contain what you need, including these fields:

`quotaBytesTotal`
The total number of quota bytes.

`quotaBytesUsed`
The number of quota bytes used.

`quotaBytesUsedInTrash`
The number of quota bytes used by trashed items.

`quotaBytesUsedAggregate`
The number of quota bytes used by all Google apps (Drive, Picasa, etc.).